# Hamburger menu React typescript with styled component

Tags: navbar, styled-components, react-typescript, hamburger-menu

do you have any reference for creating hamburger menu in react typescript?.I've tried to make it by changing from js to ts, but it ends with an error. and when I see tutorials on YouTube I find it very difficult to understand. help me what should i do

i want to replace my slicing ui result with react js with react ts. but I'm stuck on the part of making the hamburger menu.